# overwrite np.ndarray __getitem__

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subclassing

##### Target

I'm dealing with 2D time-series data, and never use negative indexing. So I want to subclass np.ndarray that negative and out-of-bound indexing in axis 0 will return a nan-augmented matrix with suitable shape. For example,

```py
>>> test
>>> array([[0, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 5]])

Target:
>>> test[-1:1]   # np.array([0, 1, 2])
>>> array(
[[nan, nan, nan],
[0, 1, 2]])

>>> test[1:4]   # np.array([3, 4, 5])
>>> array([
[3, 4, 5],
[nan, nan, nan],
[nan, nan, nan]])
```

An ideal solution is to overwrite __getitem__, test whether the first slice contains negative or out-of-bound indexing, alter it, pass in super().__getitem__, and concatenate output with appropriate nan array.

Here is an example class to test what is passed in when we index a ndarray. However, the output is wierd

```py
class NoneNeg(np.ndarray):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print(key)
        return super(NoneNeg, self).__getitem__(index)

>>> test.view(NoneNeg)
>>>(-2, -3)
(-2, -2)
(-2, -1)
(-1, -3)
(-1, -2)
(-1, -1)
NoneNeg([[0, 1, 2],
         [3, 4, 5]])
```

#### Question

1. What will be passed in when indexing ndarray? For example, test[:, 2] and test[2]. A guess could be (slice(None), 2) and (2,).
2. Why there are some negative indexing tuple output before a viewed object? It seems I can't alter negative indexing since it happens everywhere.

Comment: For a start at least, write a function to do the desired action, rather than subclassing and modifying a method.  Focus on getting the action right, not on using index notation.

Comment: You can define a dummy class with a `__getitem__` that just prints the argument and see for yourself empirically. But your first guess is right, but your second guess is wrong, it's not a tuple (no comma!). It's just `2`

Comment: When you grow an array, the result is a whole new array, not any sort of `view`.  And `np.nan` is float, so the result will be float dtype.  `np.lib.index_tricks.py` has a number of functions (instances actually) to play games with `__getitem__`.  You might find those instructive.

Comment: @hpaulj Just want other attributes to stay the same. And index_tricks.py do help me learn more about getitem, thanks a lot. And I'm still curious about the default behavior of getitem, (-2, -3), (-2, -2), etc.